# Pointer unexpectedly pointing to a value and not an address

Tags: c, pointers

```
int changeValue(int *a) {
    *a = 4;
     printf("a points to: %d\n", a);
     return 0;

}
int main() {
    int* b = NULL;
    printf("b points to : %d \n",b);
    changeValue(&b);
    printf("b points to : %d\n", b);
}
```

The output I get is that `b` points to 0, `a` points to some address -- all as expected -- but then suddenly I get `b` points to 4.

Why is it not pointing to an address?

I have also noticed if I try to display the actual value of `*b` I get a read access violation

Comment: `changeValue(&b);` should bark compiler warnings at you. If it doesn't, turn up your warning levels, and always treat them as errors. `&b` is `int**` ; the argument to the function should be `int*`. That along should tell you something is probably amiss with `b` to start with.

Comment: What compiler are you using? How are you invoking it? If invoked correctly, you should get a lot of warnings about this code. I'm not sure why you attempted to run it, and what behavior you expected from it. My suggestion is to compile with flags like `-Wall -Werror -Wextra -O2 -g` in `gcc`/`clang` and resolve all the problems, then try running the code.

Comment: The code is doing what you write : change the contents of b variable, so even if b is a pointer, it is now pointing to address 4. So, its contents is correct but it points to invalid address and this will cause an exception when using *b

Answer (score 0):

**You can't get value of nullptr, this will raise a nullptr exception.**

```
#include <stdio.h>
int changeValue(int* a) {
    *a = 4;
    printf("a points to: %p a's value is: %d\n", a, *a);
    return 0;
}
int main() {
    int a = 0;
    int* b = &a;
    printf("b points to : %p \n", b);
    changeValue(b);
    printf("b points to : %p\n", b);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: "*nullptr exception*" -- it seems you are more accustomed to C++, whereas this is a C program. Are you identifying NULL dereferencing as the *only* issue with the code? There's a lot more wrong with the code... might be nice to actually explain these in your answer. The OP's code would not compile without throwing a whole bunch of warnings (in both C and C++), and it seems the OP is ignoring those warnings.

Comment: Yes, I rarely use C. BTW MSVC don't show any warnings. And i try to compile with gcc don't show anything.
https://prnt.sc/101vvvk

Answer (score 0):

It generates 4 warnings on gcc, so I will break it down.

1. In changeValue function, make it *a while printing, or else you get a warning that %d was expected while you gave an int*
2. In main, printf for b shows address pointed to and not value of b.
3. Make the function to changeValue(b) because b is already a pointer.

Now, note that %d and b still generate a warning here but this is just to show the output.

```
#include<stdio.h>
int changeValue(int *a) {
    *a = 4;
     printf("a points to: %d\n", *a);
     return 0;
}

int main() {
    int* b = NULL;
    int a = 999;
    printf("b points to : %d \n",b);
    b = &a;
    printf("b has address %d points to : %d \n",b, *b);
    changeValue(b);
    printf("b points to : %d\n", *b);
}
```

If I run the above code, the following is what I obtain as output.

```
b points to : 0
b has address 799914380 points to : 999
a points to: 4
b points to : 4
```

Now we can see that printf with %d and only a pointer b prints its address while *b prints its value. Note that if you try to *b when b is NULL, you will get segfaults.